# Perform the segue from table view to the web view error

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9-beta

I run into an error when I try to perform the segue from table view to the web view (for youtube videos). I attached the Code for both views, the error and the target output from console. It seems to be a problem with the WKWebView class... but I don't get any error related with that.

Sender:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let partyRock = partyRocks[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "VideoVC", sender: partyRock)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? VideoVC {
        if let party = sender as? PartyRock {
            destination.partyRock = party
        }
    }
}
```

Destination:

```
import UIKit

class VideoVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLbl: UILabel!

private var _partyRock: PartyRock!
var partyRock: PartyRock {
    get {
        return _partyRock
    } set {
        _partyRock = newValue
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    titleLbl.text = partyRock.videoTitle
    webView.loadHTMLString(partyRock.videoURL, baseURL: nil)
}
}
```

The console output:

```
2017-08-18 13:33:10.460227+0300 TableViews-YoutubeVideo[49329:7366415] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_context_get_peer_sct_list: line 1739 received sct extension length is less than sct data length
2017-08-18 13:33:16.756971+0300 TableViews-YoutubeVideo[49329:7366015] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named WKWebView'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fbc626b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c324f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fc3aba5 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   UIKit                               0x000000010cfae7cc UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 323
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010cfaeae7 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1118
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010cfae67e -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010c99041f -[UIView initWithCoder:] + 969
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010cfae949 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010cfae67e -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010cd631fb -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 178
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010cfae949 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010cfaeae7 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1118
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010cfae67e -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010cd623f8 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1262
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010ca8dd49 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 383
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010ca8e652 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010ca8e983 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 195
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010ca8f1e0 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010d4e639d -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 89
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010ca5fa8f -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 133
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010caa2338 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 3808
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010caa514a __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 134
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010caa55ea -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 532
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010caa5086 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 181
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010caaa487 -[UIViewController _showViewController:withAction:sender:] + 274
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010d0349a4 __66-[UIStoryboardShowSegueTemplate newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke + 134
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010d1e8dcb -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 279
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010d1e8c83 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82
    28  UIKit                               0x000000010ca91bc4 -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 99
    29  TableViews-YoutubeVideo             0x000000010ba025c1 _T023TableViews_YoutubeVideo6MainVCC9tableViewySo07UITableH0C_10Foundation9IndexPathV14didSelectRowAttF + 273
    30  TableViews-YoutubeVideo             0x000000010ba0266c _T023TableViews_YoutubeVideo6MainVCC9tableViewySo07UITableH0C_10Foundation9IndexPathV14didSelectRowAttFTo + 92
    31  UIKit                               0x000000010ca2d603 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1810
    32  UIKit                               0x000000010ca2d81e -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 344
    33  UIKit                               0x000000010c900739 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 318
    34  UIKit                               0x000000010c8eef81 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 280
    35  UIKit                               0x000000010c91f0d8 _afterCACommitHandler + 137
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fb68e57 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fb68dae __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fb4d3c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1572
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fb4cb29 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    40  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001122589c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    41  UIKit                               0x000000010c8f49a4 UIApplicationMain + 159
    42  TableViews-YoutubeVideo             0x000000010ba06757 main + 55
    43  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000110ce8621 start + 1
    44  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522066/could-not-instantiate-class-named-mkmapview

Comment: Looks like a problem with a nib. Have you added an exception breakpoint to see what causes this?

Comment: In your viewcontroller you use a `UIWebView`. The error message talks about a `WKWebView`. That sounds strange.

Comment: did you notice in Xcode9 that the UIWebView is deprecated (at least is what is mention in the storyboard when you trying to select one). I suggest you try to use WKWebView instead. I will be glad if you let me know if this worked out for you.

Comment: yes your solution worked. thanks :)